# Multiple select option and CSS style with float on Mozilla

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to modify the CSS of a multiple select. I'm ok with the result on Chrome but i can't manage to make it work on Mozilla. The float on the option make it take full width. Because it's hard to describe like this here is what i'm trying to do :

```js
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
    return false;
});
```

```css
  select[multiple='true'] option{
      float:left;
      border: solid 1px #71aa29;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 2px;
      transition:0.2s ease;
      cursor:pointer;
  }

  select[multiple='true']{
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  select[multiple='true']>option:checked, select[multiple='true']>option:hover {
    background: #71aa29 linear-gradient(0deg, #71aa29 0%, #71aa29 100%);
    color:#ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  multiple="true">    
  <option >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Molestias,</option>
  <option >Consectetur adipisicing elit.</option>
  <option >Similique alias</option>
  <option >Maiores fugiat voluptate</option>
  <option >Molestiae modi amet eaque qui atque eius</option>
  <option >Magni, doloremque hic consequatur minus</option>
  <option >Voluptatem libero maxime porro.</option>
</select>
```

I will be glad for any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think the following gives you what you want.

```
select[multiple='true'] option{
    display: inline-block; /* no float inline-block instead */
    border: solid 1px #71aa29;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    transition:0.2s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer.
The problem with the inline-block is that there is no line break with the select.
If you have an idea.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Doesn't setting a width on the parent element cause it to wrap? Maybe if you set up a JSFiddle I can see what you mean?

Comment: Here is a JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wrhwofq1/ I added a container with a width but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: I see the problem. I had a play around with this but I couldn't fix it with a select box. I came up with the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mge9jqzz/39/ It uses checkboxes but you shoudl still get the form values through the same I believe?!